# unable to trigger Ajax by change event in my page

Tags: jquery, ajax

My ajax is not working, I am trying to read data from a connecDatabase.php when there is a change in my diary page content, please help me out. `#diary` is the id of the diary page, and when I type something on that page I want to be alerted a message which says  `{"Data Saved: " + msg }` the msg is the data from the `connectDatabase.php` file.

```
$("#diary").bind('input propertychange', function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "connectDatabase.php",
    data: {
      content: $("#diary").val()
    }
  });
  .done(function(msg) {
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: `bind()` is deprecated, you should be using `on()`.

Comment: Is this code at the end of the HTML or inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the AJAX? If you put an alert before the AJAX, do you see it?

Comment: The semicolon before .done shouldn't be there.

Comment: have you tried ````$('#diary').change(function(){........});```` or you can try ````$('#diary').on('change', function(){........});````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JohnSheridan That might be a copying error, because it should be getting a syntax error with that. To the OP: are there any errors in the console? And if there are, why didn't you fix them before posting here?